# Exception occure in Audio recording

Tags: android, exception, sd-card, audio-recording

I am creating one recording application. I need to record audio and store it in SD
card. But when i try to run the application it run fine but when i am press stop button it show message "unfortunately your application has been stop"
Here is logcat

```
enter code here  
08-01 12:09:18.331: E/SoundRecordingActivity(5611): sdcard access error
08-01 12:09:21.043: D/AndroidRuntime(5611): Shutting down VM
08-01 12:09:21.043: W/dalvikvm(5611): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2c3381f8)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at com.blitze.recordingapp.SoundRecordingActivity$2.onClick(SoundRecordingActivity.java:110)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14115)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-01 12:09:21.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 12:09:23.759: W/System.err(5611): java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
08-01 12:09:23.759: W/System.err(5611):     at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:496)
08-01 12:09:23.759: W/System.err(5611):     at android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:725)
08-01 12:09:23.759: W/System.err(5611):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:82)
08-01 12:09:23.759: W/System.err(5611):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
08-01 12:09:23.759: W/System.err(5611):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
08-01 12:09:23.759: W/System.err(5611):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startButton.setEnabled(false);
            stopButton.setEnabled(true);

            File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            try {
                audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", sampleDir);

            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();




            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
                return;
            }



        }
    });
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            startButton.setEnabled(true);
            stopButton.setEnabled(false);
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();

            //counter.cancel();
            addRecordingToMediaLibrary();

        }
    });

protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

I attached SD card to mobile. 
I don't understand what is the problem. Give me any hint or reference.
Thank you..

Comment: Do you have the sdcard write permission in manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ? It looks like the first line of your log shows "sd card access error"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at line number 110 which is a line in your OnClick function.  You will be referencing something like "recorder.stop()" and recorder at this point will be NULL.

It looks like you need to pass an instance of the recorder object that you create in the start function, into the stop function.